# Entity Validation Error - Seems To Be Loading Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I have the following classes:

```
public class Venue : BaseObject, IBaseObject
{
    [Required]
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Region")]
    [Required]
    public virtual StandingData Region { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Country")]
    [Required]
    public virtual StandingData Country { get; set; }

}
```

And

```
public class StandingData : BaseObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

My model builder looks like:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Venue>().HasRequired(x => x.Region);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Venue>().HasRequired(x => x.Country);
    }
```

I get the following validation errors:

"The field 'Region' is required"

"The field 'Country' is required"

I first noticed this in my unit tests, then in my real web UI. It only occurs when running through it on the website. If i put a breakpoint in my controller before UNIT OF WORK SAVE is called it doesn't happen it seems to be like a loading issue but I am not sure.

Has anyone else experienced this?

I really don't understand why it doesn't happen when I slowly step through the program which defenetly makes me think it's some sort of loading/lazy loading issue.

--UPDATE--

If i do this before saving the object:

```
        var t = venue.Region;
        var tt = venue.Country;
```

It doesnt error?

Why is this?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to save a new venue with a null country and region?

Comment: In the Venue class, try putting foreign key id references for both Region and Country (eg. int RegionId and int CountryId).

Comment: non threadsafe use of context by any chance?

Comment: How would i make it thread safe?

Comment: When i inspect this element i can see both region/country which is cant understand

Comment: Updated are you able to take a look?

Comment: How does the `venue` know its Region if it isn't loaded? What happens in the UoW Save method?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but a way to debug what is going on, to large for comment.
To see if the context context is really ok or not.
Are there entries there you didnt expect etc....

Inside your MyContext Class:

```
 public void FullDump()
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("=====Begin of Context Dump=======");
        var dbsetList = this.ChangeTracker.Entries();
        foreach (var dbEntityEntry in dbsetList)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(dbEntityEntry.Entity.GetType().Name + " => " + dbEntityEntry.State);
            switch (dbEntityEntry.State)
            {
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached:
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged:
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added:
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified:
                    WriteCurrentValues(dbEntityEntry);
                    break;
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted:
                    WriteOriginalValues(dbEntityEntry);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("==========End of Entity======");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("==========End of Context======");
    }
```

You can call this from Immediate Window

```
 `MyContext.FullDump()`
```

Comment: Updated are you able to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564

Check the recommended ways of declaring relationships eg

```
public class Venue : BaseObject, IBaseObject
{
[Required]
public virtual User Owner { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(40)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("RegionId")]
[DisplayName("Region")]
[Required]
public virtual int RegionId { get; set; } // cant see baseObject so I just assume int

[ForeignKey("CountryId")]
[DisplayName("Country")]
[Required]
public int  CountryId { get; set; }


// nav props
public virtual StandingData Region { get; set; }
public virtual StandingData Country { get; set; }

}
```